# Django template filter extract from list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

My view context dictionary produces a list of footage numbers (eg. [1200, 1137, 1428, 5774... ]). I have corresponding tags in my template that pull specific list members...

```
<td> {{ footage | slice:"-1:" }}</td><td> {{ footage | slice:"-2:-1" }}</td><td> {{ footage | slice:"-3:-2" }}</td><td> {{ footage | slice:"-4:-3" }}</td>
```

problem is – when rendered, the html displays the values as a list with a single value – as opposed to a standalone string...

[image: screen grab of rendered table]

how can I extract the values from the brackets (pull them from the lists)?

Comment: Don't implement business logic in the *template*. Business logic should be written in the *view*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do `{{footage.0}}`.

Or in your example if you want to list them all in reverse order you can do:

```
{% for f in footage reversed %}
 {{f}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: reversed the lists in the view per Willem, and referenced values in template using the syntax you advised.